# How to run iex as normal user?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm following [this link](https://gist.github.com/rubencaro/6a28138a40e629b06470) to install elixir and erlang on fedora 21... After i installed when i tried to run interactive elixir(iex) i get the following error

```
/home/hari/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.4.2/bin/elixir: line 126: exec: erl: not found
```

Commands i used to install :

```
asdf install erlang 19.0
asdf install elixir 1.3.2
```

But if i run as a root user its working correctly!!! What's the mistake im commiting here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a path issue. Please do the following to detect the problem root:

```
sudo su -c 'which erl' 
#⇒ /usr/local/bin/erl # OR LIKE
```

It seems that this directory *is not on your user’s path*. Add it to test:

```
export PATH=`dirname $(sudo su -c 'which erl')`:$PATH
```

Try running elixir (it should succeed.) Now just put the hardcoded path in the very end of your shell start script (`~/.bashrc` if you use bash, etc):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: when i run this command i get  which: no erl in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
dirname: missing operand

Comment: You can’t get this when running `sudo which erl`. Please share the output of running `which erl` **as a root user**.

Comment: am getting output like /root/.asdf/shims/erl

Comment: Jeez. You happened to run `asdf install erlang 19.0 && asdf install elixir 1.3.2` as a root user. Please run those as normal user and, in general, just stop logging in as a root user, otherwise sooner or later you’ll be hacked. For now, rerun `asdf` as normal user and you are done.

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan If this solved your problem, then please mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the checkmark button next to it)

Comment: @mudasobwa after i install those services as normal user,is it possible to make those services avalibale for other users??

Comment: asdf is invented to be per user install. Just install erlang and elixir normally, via system package manager.

Comment: On Fedora the package manager would be yum. Maybe dnf but I think for Fedora 21 it's yum.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci dnf working without any issue, a reason which i use asdf is to install elixir with required version